# How to change an Image extension when user click to bottom to open it?

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an image folder which contains .tif image and when the user search for an image the image must be **.png** or ***.jpeg*** file extension to avoid browser incompatibilities while display **.tif** images. How can i do that? Please, notice that the images are save in a directory, not in a database.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I didn't understand whether you want to convert an image or just change an extension. Also, what have you tried already?

Comment: What need is, once the user search a document that docment is being found, the user will have a bottom that will display the image, the images are in .tif format and i need them in .png format to avoid problems. Its like change the image extension but not save it, i just want to DISPLAY the image.

Answer (score 2):

[TIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format), or  "Tag Image File Format", is a raw file format with little or no compression. [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) and [JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) are both compressed formats.

You're going to have to find a way to write PNG & JPEG files or install some SDK plugin to do this.

You can't just change the extension and display a TIF as one of these compressed formats.

Links provided for WIKI references.

Hope that helps.